# Why does my website work only on my machine?

Tags: html, css

I have uploaded [a website to the internet](http://midiamantedegel.com).

Firebug claims that no file is missing and yet on both IE and FF it doesn't look good as expected and also the script doesn't work (no errors).

***However, on my own computer (or any offline machine), it works perfectly fine.***

Here are the [files](https://dl-web.getdropbox.com/get/Agel%20Premotional%20Site.rar?w=fa40df17).

And here is a screenshot:

[image]

Any thoughts on why this happens? What's missing?

Comment: I cannot see any differences between your screenshot and what I'm seeing in a browser.  Could you point out where the differences between your expected output and the actual output are?

Comment: LOL you can't because I just fixed it :)

Comment: @T Pops: I have to wait 48 hours before I can accept my own answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the problem was this:

> The site currently on line and the
>   files you sent aren't identical.  the
>   images in the sent file are correct.
>   if you compare the two you'll see that
>   the images on line are LARGER then
>   they should be and that is why the
>   site looks off. It is NOT a CSS issue
>   - the images just need to be replaced with the images in the correct size.
>   I'm mailing you the full site you sent
>   me again with the correct images only.
>   Please scrub the server from ALL
>   IMAGES on it and then re-install the
>   site with the correct images.

This is from my designer.
Strange that the subversion wasn't updated.

Answer (score 1):

Check for any differences in cases in files' names. If your developing on Windows (case-insensitive), and uploading files to a *nix server (case-sensitive), this would easily lead to file-not-found errors.

Comment: all files are found according to Firebug.

Comment: The problem is clearly related to filenames. If you look into the files folder, "midiamantedegel.com/files/", you will se that the linked filenames do NOT match the files in the folder. Eg. "EXOESP.pdf" vs. "ExoEsp.pdf". Or misspellings like "PREOESP.pdf" vs. "PROESP.pdf". The file "CALESP.pdf" doesn't even exist on the server.

Comment: thanks for the heads up on the missing file.
I'll inform the client.

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens to me when I leave console.log statements in, by mistake. It works on my machine because I've got firebug -- my clients' machines don't, so the scripts break.

Your files link requires a login, so I couldn't see them.

Comment: I don't have any console.log at all.

Answer (score 0):

How did you upload the files? We had similar issue when copying between virtual servers. Everything seemed perfect but they dont work properly as you said. Then we used xcopy to move the files.

Try uploading them using a good FTP client. Also please post a screenshot of how it should look.